# LinQ2SQL using Take to pick top n

Tags: linq-to-sql

Does Take(N) executes after getting full list or the execution stope after picking the needed top n records

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Take(n) will translate into a Top on older versions of SQL server and ROW_NUMBER on newer versions on the SQL side, if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx#2625138) LINQ2SQL uses the `ROW_NUMBER` function in SQL Server to implement the `Take(n)` method. So it's done by the database and not by the client on the full result set.

Answer (score 0):

```
this
  .Where(t +> t.Something == 1)
  .Take(5)
```

Will take the first 5 elements satisfying condition. It will NOT return the whole data set.

Take runs after the deferred execution.

Kindness,

Dan